# WPF ListView Grouping - with a twist

Tags: wpf

I have a treeview right now with a templateselector. Basically each tree node on the root is a "category" of some type of data and each child node under those are displayed in a specific way (via the template selector).

This allows me to show different data in a single control easily just using binding. My problem is that it's not working out so well visually. I would like to have a grid style (ListView.GridView) under each root node.

I was looking at ListView grouping but is it possible to define different columns for each group? Since I doubt that is possible, what are some options? I would like to allow the user to expand and collapse the groups just like a treeview but see a GridView under each node with scroll bars, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that ListView supports different headers in groups. It's just grouping of rows. Looks like you're going to have to create a new ListView under each tree node. You might try a data grid. In WinForms you can bind to multiple tables and the grid will group by table which can be expanded and collapsed which would in effect show different columns. If you're using MVVM (I assume some collection or hierarchy model) I have no idea how you'd accomplish that with a data grid.

Comment: not enough answers so I suppose you're correct and that is what i'm doing. Maybe I need to rethink the design.

Answer (score -1):

You may achieve what you want relatively simple if you adopt the [MVVM architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Each node on the tree is of a certain type (ViewModel). Each data type would be bind to a specific View. Each View can be a ListView with any columns you want.

I recommend you read about MVVM and adopt it in order to achievewhat you need. I found that the adoption of MVVM leads to applications with a much cleaner architecture and code.

Comment: I'm already using MVVM and i'm already using your suggested technique to render my current tree hence the templateselector.

Comment: If you have a different view for each type of node, you can render each node as a different ListView with the number of columns you desire.